# Getting different error in different browsers while use "AND" and "normalize-space" in a Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have following simple button in my webpage -

```
<button type="button" class=" m-form-btn" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
```

As class name having one white space So I'm Using `normalize-space()` -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button'][normalize-space(@class='m-form-btn')]")).click();
```

Which is Working fine in right way but while I do use `AND` in this way-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' AND normalize-space(@class='m-form-btn')]")).click();

//or

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space(@class)='m-form-btn' AND @type='button']")).click();
```

Getting Error in `Firefox` -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45
>   -0700' System info: host: 'TSS167', ip: '192.168.1.167', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_91' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false,
>   marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}},
>   appBuildId=20161208153507, version=, platform=XP, proxy={},
>   command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false,
>   processId=7824, browserVersion=50.1.0, platformVersion=6.3,
>   XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox,
>   takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true,
>   platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID:
>   30ed9c92-2d49-4c7b-83bc-c1638e24b3e8  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
>     at ClassEight.main(ClassEight.java:28) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was:
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:322)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:284)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes.toStatus(ErrorCodes.java:138)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:92)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     ... 5 more

And Following error for the same in `Chrome` -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //button[normalize-space(@class)='m-form-btn' AND @type='button']
>   because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute
>   'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//button[normalize-space(@class)='m-form-btn' AND @type='button']' is
>   not a valid XPath expression.

I did `evaluate` both `xpath` using `firepath` where I'm Getting the expected output.

I don't know what causing the problem, I'm using `AND` with `normalize-space` Is it so ? or anything I'm doing wrong ?

Using `selenium 3.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `OR` or `AND` in uppercase in `XPath` is wrong way (at least in `Selenium`). You should use `or`/`and` instead. So try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space(@class)='m-form-btn' and @type='button']")).click();
```